# Can Visual Studio (Community Edition) warn of incorrect comparisons in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio, conditional-statements, compiler-warnings

I teach a basic C programming course. I encounter a lot of submissions that contain code like this:

```
int num = 0;
// ...
if (1 < num < 3) {
  // ...
}
```

While this is valid python, it will not work in C. When using Eclipse and gcc/MinGW, I get a warning that this is incorrect usage. However, when I use Visual Studio (Community Edition), this does not produce any warnings. Is there a way to enable warnings on this type of code in Visual Studio? Enabling `/Wall` did not help.

Comment: You have [C4804](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4804), no? https://godbolt.org/z/39safeo71

Comment: @AlexGuteniev seems to be C++ related?

Comment: @AlexGuteniev you compiled C++ but op asked about C

Comment: gcc issues a warning as an extension. Strictly speaking, it is a perfectly valid conditional, although it is (most likely) not what the developer intended. There is no requirement in the standard for diagnostics to be produced to help the developer.

Comment: No, there is no requirement, but something obviously wrong such as a boolean expression always evaluating to true should at least be mentioned by the compiler. Apparently, gcc will do it even if VS won't. Guess which one I will be recommending for beginners? Sorry, Microsoft, you lose again.

Comment: @EricSokolowsky: We do not always want Boolean expressions that are always true to generate warnings. In some cases, they may arise from conditional compilation where they will be false in circumstances not evident to the compiler. E.g., `int` may be 16 bits or 32 (or other sizes), and some combinations of build settings may produce comparisons that are always true when `int` is 16 bits but not when `int` is 32 bits. It may be undesirable to treat these as problems, so some selectivity in compiler generation of warnings is desired.

Comment: The warning C4804 is indeed missing when compiling this code in C. Because in C the comparison result isn't `bool`, so nothing suspicious happens. It require some deeper analysis from the compiler side to issue a warning here.  Probably it worth reporting https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com , but I'm not sure if C compiler warnings have some priority these days...

Comment: Reported https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/warning-about-suspicious-comparison-is-not-emitted/1590522

Comment: Microsoft's C compiler is known for being defective in one way or the other. The C++ compiler is a bit better. Anyway, you might want to insert a static code checker into your check pipeline.